# Changing Json Data, getting TypeError

Tags: python, json, dictionary, typeerror

**Edit**: Turns out my whole problem was my Json had already been converted to a dictionary previously, without me realising. And I was using json.dumps() instead of .loads() by mistake.

**Original Q**:I have a piece of Json code I have turned into a dictionary. I am retrieving this Json from a server. When I try access the inner values of the new dictionary to change a value, I get a:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

This is my code:

```
corner_data = json.dumps(r.json())

print corner_data

corner_data["geometry"]["corners"] = '{"bottom_right": {"y": "575.531616", "x": "690.547363"}, "top_left": {"y": "-146.739075", "x": "-109.105957"}}'
```

Comment: `obj['key']['key']['key'] = 'foobar'`...!? Assuming you've decoded the JSON to the dict `obj`.

Comment: The json data is multi layered. I need to access and internal layer, and change one piece to another piece of json

Comment: Again: decode the JSON to a dict, access and manipulate the dict as above, encode again to JSON. Have you tried something along those lines?

Comment: I change the json to a dict using json.dumps(), but when i try access it says something about needs a number not a letter

Comment: That means that you're accessing an element of a list. JSON objects in Python are dictionaries but it can have lists as inner values, so you need to account for that.

Comment: You want `loads`, not `dumps`. Also, if you already have code which has some problem, post that code and ask a question about it.

Comment: [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) for [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or[`simplejson`](http://simplejson.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: @IanAuld thanks, but just getting into programming, don't really understand what's going on there

Comment: Now seems like a good a time as any to learn.

Comment: `json.dumps` turns a Python dict/list/object into JSON. You're trying to do the opposite, JSON → dict. That's what `json.loads` does.

Comment: But i started with json. I'm asking how would i modify it within a python script. My only thought was to turn into dictionary, then change, than convert back to json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the JSON string into a Python dict using ***`json.loads`*** (not `dumps`!):*

```
corner_data = json.loads(r.json())
```

Modify the data, assigning a Python dict (not a string!):

```
corner_data['geometry']['corners'] = {'bottom_right': {'y': '575.531616', 'x': '690.547363'}, 'top_left': {'y': '-146.739075', 'x': '-109.105957'}}
```

Encode it all back into JSON:

```
print json.dumps(corner_data)
```

* I'm assuming here that `r.json()` returns a *string*. It's entirely possible that `r.json()` already decodes a JSON string and returns a dict, that depends on what `r` is. If that's the case, you don't need `json.loads` here, you can simply omit it.

Comment: Getting a: ` TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: Th is the json i am getting from server `{u'status': u'S', u'vendor': 1, u'name': u'test', u'created': u'2015-07-10T14:06:12.707759Z', u'geometry': {u'corners': None, u'photo': 1085, u'id': 749, u'room': {u'vanishing_points': [{u'y': u'8152.308', u'x': u'537.9231'}, {u'y': u'241.1388', u'x': u'4747.204'}, {u'y': u'256.0742', u'x': u'271.5687'}]}},  u'image_name': u'd17efc0e-ddad-45ca-8bbf-59f7267e0d62.raw_image', u'region_image': None, u'image_width': 1024, u'user': 287, u'modified': u'2015-07-10T14:06:13.223489Z', u'image_height': 768, u'id': 1085}
`

Comment: That's not JSON, that's already a decoded Python dict. My footnote seems to be correct then. So just do `corner_data = r.json()`.

Comment: Thanks so much. My whole problem came down to, what i thought was json from the server, was actually a python dict.

Comment: Hint: `print type(corner_data)`

Comment: Will do in future. I was using python-requests to get data from server, maybe that is converting from Json to dictionary automatically?

Comment: Well, yes, that's exactly what `.json()` does! It *decodes* a JSON response. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content